# Rails 4 App - JS works with Webrick but not Passenger/Apache2 in Development Mode

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, apache, coffeescript, passenger

The form first uses js to populate a product select list based on selecting a category.  This works.  Then it should toggle different divs based on which product is selected in the product select box.

The first part of the coffeescript file works fine.  The second part works if I serve the page with Webrick, but not via Apache2/Passenger.  I get no errors in the log files, nor in the IE debugger (yeah, right) - the divs just don't show up.

Does anyone know why part of the file works all of the time and the other part only works some of the time?

I thought it might be an asset pipeline issue, but then neither of the functions would work, right?  I am running this in DEVELOPMENT mode.  Thanks in advance for any help.

**_form.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_for(@request) do |f| %>
      <% if @request.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@request.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this request from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% @request.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <% if current_user %>
        <% if current_user.analyst %>   
          <div class="field">
            <font color="maroon">Check here for an IT Project-Related Request that has already been budgeted and does not require further departmental approvals :</font>   <%= f.check_box :project %>
          </div>
       <% end %>
      <% end %>   
      <p></p>

      <!-- SHOW ONLY CATEGORIES WITH ACTIVE PRODUCTS -->
      <div class="field" id="category">
        <%= f.label :category_id, "Select a Category:" %>
        <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.sorted, :id, :name, :include_blank => true ) %>
      </div>

      <!--  BASED ON CATEGORY SELECTED ABOVE, LOAD CORRESPONDING ACTIVE PRODUCTS BELOW -->
        <div class="field" id="product">
        <%= f.label :product_id, "Select a Product/Service:" %>
        <%= f.grouped_collection_select :product_id, Category.active.sorted, :active_products, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
      </div>

      <!--  BASED ON PRODUCT SELECTED ABOVE, SHOW CORRESPONDING PRODUCT.DESCRIPTION AND CORRESPONDING DIV BELOW IF APPLICABLE -->

      <div class="field" id="product_description"> 
      <!-- <%#= @request.product.description %> ..... show the product.description of the product selected above -->
      </div>

      <div class="field" id="quantity">
        <%= f.label :quantity, "Quantity:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
      </div>

      <p></p>

      <div id="dynamic_portion">
                <!--<-- These are the custom DIVS that need to load based on the product_id selected above:-->

      </div>



      <!--  ALWAYS SHOW TEXT AREA FOR FURTHER INFO -->

        <div class="field" id="requestor_note">
            <%= f.label :requestor_note, "Please give full details below..." %>
            <%= f.text_area :requestor_note, :size => "50x6" %>
        </div>

        </br><p></p>
      <div>
        <%= f.submit "Submit", :name => nil, :class => "btn" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

**requests_controller.rb:**

```
      def refresh_dynamic_content
        @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        if @product.id == 8
          render :partial => 'requests/new_city_employee' ,:layout => false
        elsif @product.id == 10
          render :partial => 'requests/exit_employee' ,:layout => false
        elsif @product.id == 12 or @product.id == 21
          render :partial => 'requests/change_employee' ,:layout => false
        end
      end
```

**requests.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->

#//this handles product population based on category select - this works with Webrick and Phusion/Apache2

    $('#request_product_id').parent().hide()
    products = $('#request_product_id').html()
    emptyOption = $('<option />').attr('value', '');
    $('#request_category_id').change ->
        category = $('#request_category_id :selected').text()
        options = $(products).filter("optgroup[label='#{category}']").prepend(emptyOption).html()
        if options
            $('#request_product_id').html(options)
            $('#request_product_id').parent().show()
        else
            $('#request_product_id').empty()
            $('#request_product_id').parent().hide()


#// this should handle <div> toggle based on product select - this works with Webrick, but not Phusion Passenger/Apache2:

$("#request_product_id").change ->
  trial = $("#request_product_id option:selected").val()
  container = $("#dynamic_portion")
  $.ajax
    url: "/refresh_content?product_id=" + trial
    type: "get"
    dataType: "html"
    processData: false
    success: (data) ->
      container.html data
```

**Update - Firebug:**

When running with Apache/Passenger, I get this:

```
Request URL:
    http://server/refresh_content?product_id=10

    Request Method:
    GET

    Status Code:
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

When running in Webrick, I get this:

```
Request URL:
    http://localhost:3000/refresh_content?product_id=10

      Request Method:
      GET

    Status Code:
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

When running apache, it is serving from the server root, not the application root - ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the ajax url from:

```
url: "/refresh_content?product_id=" + trial
```

to:

```
url: "/requests/refresh_content?product_id=" + trial
```

And now it works. Thank you, Firebug.